# New relic not acknowledging metric data

Tags: newrelic-platform

I am sending the following json:

```
{
  "components": [
    {
      "guid": "com.mycompany.MyPlugin",
      "duration": 60,
      "metrics": {
        "Component/Memory/Heap Used[bytes]": 146990608,
        "Component/Processor/GC[percent]": 0.5555555555555556,
        "Component/Memory/Heap Max[bytes]": 39387136,
        "Component/Processor/CPU[percent]": 66.66666666666667,
        "Component/Memory/Heap Committed[bytes]": 279714288
      },
      "name": "MyPlugin"
    }
  ],
  "agent": {
    "host": "host",
    "pid": 0,
    "version": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

The `Component/Memory/*` metrics are properly recognized by new relic and i am able to create dashboards.

But, the `Component/Processor/*` metrics dont seem to acknowledged at all. I cant see them in the dropdown list of metric names when i create a new dashboard and even typing the name manually doesn't work since new relic says no such metric exists.

Comment: Have you gotten a resolution to this? I am seeing the same problem

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended that GUID values be all lower case. At present GUIDs with differing case are treated as unique.

Comment: guids are indeed lower case. i just changed it in the pasted code to hide company info

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Try curling with your data as a test:

```
curl -vi https://platform-api.newrelic.com/platform/v1/metrics 
     -H "X-License-Key: <LICENSE_KEY>"
     -H "Content-Type: application/json"
     -H "Accept: application/json"    
     -X POST -d '<JSON_DATA>'
```

Comment: tried it. doesnt work. here is a screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/9d32OTSJ3 Also percent is just a value type, shouldnt affect the metric itself

Comment: Also, how are you sending this data? Directly to the HTTP API or are you using the Ruby, Java, or .NET SDK?

Comment: using the java sdk. the sdk shouldnt matter since i am showing you the exact post sent

Comment: Just asking about the method of sending so I know what I need to look at specifically. It shouldn't matter which method you are using. Did you try using curl as a test?

Comment: i am on windows. no curl available. again how is this relevant, if there was an http error it would be reflected in the logs and also the Memory/* metrics wouldnt be recorded

Comment: @pdeva can you open a support ticket on this? We'll be able to look at your account and hopefully get to the bottom of this. https://support.newrelic.com

Comment: i did create one yesterday, but didnt receive any replies